# Get the number of the global messages to show

Tags: magento-1.9, messages

Before calling

```
$this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml()
```

in my phtml templates file I would like to know if there are messages to show. I need something like this:

```
if($thereAreMessages) {
    echo '<div class="myWrapper">';
    $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml()
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() != NULL) {
    echo '<div class="myWrapper">';
    $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
    echo '</div>';
}
```

should work.